# How to use Gecko or WebKit if the user already has browser

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, webkit, gecko

Is there a way to use WebKit or Gecko if the user already have Chrome/Safari or Firefox installed?

Comment: It does matter for me. That's what I want.

Comment: Sigh, no, it doesn't matter that the user has selected a different favorite browser.  Webkit and Gecko run as in-process components, utterly unaffected by the user's browser preference.  With some significant downsides, all config is up to you, so is deployment.  WebBrowser is similarly unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that it may be not the answer for you question and I don't know your situation, but why you just don't include Gecko/Webkit library in your application? So you shouldn't worry about any installed browsers and that is more important - their versions.